# Is $441$ the only square of the form $\frac{397\cdot 10^n-1}{9}$?

Tags: nt.number-theory

Is $441$ the only square of the form $\frac{397\cdot 10^n-1}{9}$?

Can it be proven?

Comment: unmotivated number theory questions tend to be poorly received, you will want to provide a motivation for your question to increase the chances of a productive answer.

Comment: Why $397{{{}}}$?

Comment: I wish people wouldn't be so quick to close questions like this. If they had thought about the problem posed then they would have realised that it was non trivial. As a professional number theorist, I actually like questions like this: simple to state yet require difficult tools to solve

Comment: Also as a number theorist I have no problem with unmotivated number theory questions.

Comment: @annibalis: Is this supposed to be answered with only elementary mathematics?

Comment: @Alex M. no in any way

Comment: I respectfully disagree about whether this question is trivial or not. Note that $397 \cdot 10^{n} - 1 \equiv 3 \pmod{4}$ if $n \geq 2$ and hence it cannot be a square.

Comment: Ha, nice. I do wonder whether those who voted to close noticed this easy argument. Though for more general problems like this I guess using the Mordell equation is the way to go.

Answer (score 12):

If $\frac{397\cdot 10^n - 1}9$ is a square then so is $397\cdot 10^n - 1$. Let $y^2=397\cdot 10^n - 1$. Denoting $x:=10^{\lfloor n/3\rfloor}$, we get that
$$y^2 = 397\cdot 10^r\cdot x^3 - 1$$
or
$$(397\cdot 10^{r}y)^2 = (397\cdot 10^r\cdot x)^3 - 397^2\cdot 10^{2r}$$
where $r:=n\bmod 3\in\{0,1,2\}$. These are [Mordell equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mordell_curve) with [many known solutions](http://www.math.ubc.ca/%7Ebennett/BeGa-data.html), which in general can be solved by finding integral points on the elliptic curve.

I've solved this equation, and confirm your conjecture.

Comment: The following code snippet for Sage verifies that the only integral points on the corresponding Mordell curves are $(3970,\pm 250110)$, which corresponds to the $441$ which OP asked for. (oops, editor eats the line breaks. Not sure how to fix it)    for r in range(3):
        N = 397*10^r
        E = EllipticCurve([0,-N^2])
        print(r,E.integral_points())`

Comment: @Wojowu: Yes, I've got the same.