# How can I find all integer solutions of $3^n - x^2 = 11$

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations

I know that $n$ can't be even because of the following argument:

Let $n = 2p$. Then we can use the difference of two squares and it becomes like this :
$(3^p + x)(3^p - x) = 11; 3^p + x = 11 , 3^p - x = 1$. $3^p = 6$ which is not possible if $p$ is an integer.

I also found out that $x$ has to be an even number. I think that the only solution is $3^3 - 4^2 = 11$ but how can I find the true answer?

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1 + \sqrt{-11}}{2}]$ is a Euclidean domain.

Comment: Equations of this type are called [Ramanujan-Nagell type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan%E2%80%93Nagell_equation). This term might help find some relevant tools.

Comment: This particular equation is considered in papers [Alter & Kubota (1975)](https://doi.org/10.1016/0022-314X(75)90003-7) and [Cohen (1976)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/24490748).

Comment: Just for the record, a similar question: https://mathoverflow.net/q/384484

Answer (score 17):

One way to do this (probably not the easiest, but generalizes quite nicely) is to write $n=3m+r$ with $r\in\{0,1,2\}$. Then you have a solution $(x,3^m)\in\mathbb Z^2$ to
$$ 3^r\cdot y^3 - x^2 = 11. $$
So you just need to find the integer points on the three elliptic curves
$$ y^3-x^2=11,\quad 3y^3-x^2=11,\quad 9y^3-x^2=11. $$
There are standard methods for handling such curves.

Comment: Is there any particular reason to write $n = 3m + r$ rather than $n = 2m + r$?

Comment: @user44191 An equation $Q(x,y)=c$ with $Q$ quadratic may have infinitely many integer solutions, e.g., $x^2-Dy^2=1$. So after finding a generator for the infinitely many solutions, you'd still need to figure out which ones have their $y$-coordinate a power of 3. OTOH, an elliptic curve always has finitely many integer points; and there is in principle an effective algorithm to find them. In practice, there may be computational issues; and cleverness never hurts. I'm not sure to what extent this can be done automatically for small coefficients, e.g., in Sage or other packages.

Comment: These are further reduced to [Mordell equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mordell_curve): \begin{split} x^2&=y^3-11\\ (3x)^2 &= (3y)^3 - 99 \\ (9x)^2 &= (9y)^3 - 891\end{split} with [readily available solutions](https://personal.math.ubc.ca/~bennett/BeGa-data.html).

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev Thanks for providing the link to solve this particular case, but since the OP didn't say why this particular equation is interesting (it doesn't look so to me), I took the real question to be "how does one solve such problems." If the numbers are small enough, one can look up the answers in the link you cite (or elsewhere). If the numbers are fairly small, there are packages that will find the solutions (sometimes rigorously, sometimes with some heuristics), and if the numbers are quite large, then one may be out of luck for the present.

Comment: If one wanted to avoid MordelI equations, I guess one could use something like $|3^n -x^2| > 3^{7n/40}$, valid for all integer $x$ and odd $n$, to solve such equations, even with reasonable large numbers involved.

Comment: @MikeBennett Nice result. You should make that an answer, with a few more details, if you have a chance. Would it also work with $|2^n3^m-x^2|$? Or is it just for $|a^n-x^2|$?

Comment: To handle $|2^n3^m-x^2|$ is, perhaps oddly, much harder (at least with a lower bound that is polynomial in $x$). Even $|a^n-x^2|$ is hard for general $a$ -- the result I quote depends upon a numerical fluke!

Answer (score 6):

$$3^{n} - x^2 = 11$$

According to Silverman's answer, we take the three cases $n=3a, n=3a+1,$ and $n=3a+2.$
The problem can be reduced to finding the integer points on elliptic curves as follows.

$\bullet n=3a$
Let $X = 3^a, Y=x$, then we get  $Y^2 = X^3 - 11.$
According to [LMFDB](https://www.lmfdb.org/EllipticCurve/Q/13068/b/1), this elliptic curve has integer points $(X,Y)=(3,\pm 4), (15,\pm 58)$ with rank $2.$
Hence $(X,Y)= (3,\pm 4) \implies  (n,x)=(3,\pm4).$

$\bullet n=3a+1$
Let $X = 3^{a+1}, Y=3x$, then we get $Y^2 = X^3 - 99.$
This elliptic curve has rank $0$ and has no integer point, so there is no integer solution $(n,x).$

$\bullet n=3a+2$
Let $X = 3^{a+2}, Y=9x$, then we get    $Y^2 = X^3 - 891.$
This elliptic curve has integer points $(X,Y)=(31,\pm 170)$ with rank $1.$
Hence there is no integer solution $(n,x).$

Thus, there are only integer solutions $(n,x)=(3,\pm4).$

Comment: As I mentioned in the other comment, these are [Mordell equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mordell_curve) with [readily available solutions](https://personal.math.ubc.ca/~bennett/BeGa-data.html).

Comment: @Max Alekseyev, Thank you for your information.

Comment: Uff!  This simple angle of view gives a really astonishing blink of insight...

Comment: @Gottfried Helms, I just applied Silverman's method to the problem.
Thanks.

Comment: @Tomita I appreciate the kudos, but if you ever refer to it in an article or such, you should **not** call it "Silverman's method." It's a standard and well-known technique that I'm sure was known in the 19th century, if not earlier. I have no idea who first came up with the idea.

Comment: @Joe Silverman, I'll edit my answer.